# Bounded and converges.

Tags: real-analysis

This statement $x_1=8$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x_n+2$ for $n\in \mathbb N.$

I have to show that $(x_n)$ is bounded and monotone also.

So, consider $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{2}x_n+2-x_n=-\frac{1}{2}x_n+2.$

How i conclude this incresing or decreasing ?

Comment: My guess is that you meant $x_{n+1}=\frac12x_n+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove that $4<x_n\leq8$ for every positive integer $n$ by induction.

Then the sequence is bounded.

If it is not decreasing then some positive integer $m$ must exist with $x_m<x_{m+1}=\frac12x_m+2$ but that contradicts that $4<x_m$.

Answer (score 0):

Working from Jose's guess, if you set $y_n  =2^n x_n$ then we see that
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + 2^{n+2}$$ 
which has the solution $y_n = y_0 + 4\sum_0^{n-1} 2^k = y_0 +2^{n+2}-4$, and $y_0=x_0$ so that
$$x_n = 2^{-n}(x_0+2^{n+2}-4) = 2^{-n}(x_0-4) +4$$
So since your initial condition is $x_0 = 8 > 4$ the sequence monotonically decreases to $4$.